# Facebook put_object error: TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, facebook, typeerror

I'm getting this error since this morning, passed days the same code worked. I'm working with the [pythonforfacebook API](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk/).

This is my code:

```python
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(accesstoken)
graph.put_object(page_id, 'feed', message="Just posting something on my wall")
```

If I use 'me' instead of the page_id it works. But I need it posted on my fanpage, not my profile page. I already checked the page_id via the Graph API explorer and that is correct.

This is the error:

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/kyra/PycharmProjects/MyProject/com/facebook/Working_FB.py", line 68, in <module>
graph.put_object(page_id, 'feed', message="Just posting something on my wall")
File "C:/Users/kyra/PycharmProjects/MyProject/com/facebook/Working_FB.py", line 64, in graph.put_object
raise facebook.GraphAPIError
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: Please include the *full* traceback so we can pinpoint where it occurs.

Comment: Also provide the example where you use 'me' so we can understand that a little better too.

Comment: I just added the traceback, the example with me is the exact same thing: `graph.put_object('me', 'feed', message="Just posting something on my wall")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this happens during the creation of the exception object in

```
raise facebook.GraphAPIError
```

Obviously, `GraphAPIError` requires at least one argument.

Either provide a readily built exception object such as

```
raise facebook.GraphAPIError(whatever)
```

or give `raise` the requires argument in order to let it build that object:

```
raise facebook.GraphAPIError, whatever
```

This will, at least, remove the `TypeError` when trying to raise the exception. But why the exception raises at the first place is subject to a more concrete search in the lines above the one with `raise`.

Comment: When I do this I get the following result: `facebook.GraphAPIError: whatever`
The error I raise is also purely to see what went wrong, if I don't use it my program just crashes.

Comment: @Kyra In order to learn about that, you'd have to find out why `GraphAPIError` gets raised. There must be something wrong.

Comment: I will delete some of the error handlers I have installed in different files, maybe I will get the correct error then

Comment: Your answer did work so I accepted the answer. I've found my problem, and this needs some other solution. But I think for that problem I've found another solution. So thank you for your help